# Keep Focus To Main Control By Click/Press To Another Controls

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

I have a datagridview  and listbox control on winforms . My task is not to lost focus from datagridview on press or click to listbox control.

I want to keep focus on datagridview.

**For Example:**  when datagridview have focus and if I press or click to listbox then the datagridview lost the focus but I just want to keep focusing datagridview on press or click to listbox.
Any help will appreciated.

I have tried `datagridview.focus()` on click event of listbox but it's lost the focus from **datagridview columns1** and gain the focus to **datagridview columns2.** In short the said event and calling method is lost the focus from datagridview. I just want to keep focusing **datagridview columns1** on click to **listbox**. Is it possible?.

Answer (score 0):

How about calling `yourDataGridView.Focus();` immediately after processing the click event for the listbox?

Comment: I have tried it before but the problem is it's lost the focus from columns1 and focus to columns2. In Short datagridview lost the focus first and gain focus on click event to last columns. I want to keep focus on columns1

Comment: You should elaborate your question to include what you've already tried and what exactly you wish to accomplish. Makes it easier to offer help.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am having a similar problem where I need to pull a value from my grid selection when I launch another form but as soon as I do I lose focus so I get the value of the top record in the grid instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this at the top of your `Default.aspx.cs` page where the `Page_Load` is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true;
}
```

This should postback and leave the focus where you left off.